# How can I hide Navbar from signin, signup pages in react?

Tags: reactjs, routes, navbar, mern, react-routing

1. How can i modify my app.js file to hide Navbar for signin and signup pages, but render for other pages?
2. I want to render navbar once but screencomponents inside it should change. In navbar , I have to pass screenComponent prop in order to show content inside nav and sidebar. The code is working perfect but I don't know whether I wrote the code perfect? what is the standard way to do this task ?

   function App() {
   return (

   <Navbar screenComponent={

   ```
        <Routes>

          {/* User Profiling Routes */}

          <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
          <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path="emailsent" element={<EmailSent />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute Component={ProfileHome} />} />
          <Route path="/wish" element={<PrivateRoute Component={Wishlist} />} />
          <Route path="/add_address" element={<PrivateRoute Component={AddAddress} />} />
          <Route path="/edit_address/:id" element={<PrivateRoute Component={EditAddress} />} />
          <Route path="/add_payment" element={<PrivateRoute Component={AddPayment} />} />
          <Route path="/edit_payment/:id" element={<PrivateRoute Component={EditPayment} />} />
          <Route path="/delete_account" element={<PrivateRoute Component={DeleteAccount} />} />
          <Route path="/edit_prescription" element={<PrivateRoute Component={EditPrescriptions} />} />
          <Route path="/prescription_details" element={<PrivateRoute Component={PrescriptionDetails} />} />
          <Route path="/add_prescription" element={<PrivateRoute Component={AddPrescription} />} />
          <Route path="/change_password" element={<PrivateRoute Component={ChangePassword} />} />
          <Route path="/upload_tryon_images" element={<PrivateRoute Component={UploadTryonImages} />} />
          <Route path="/upload_user_image" element={<PrivateRoute Component={UploadUserImage} />} />
          <Route path="/giftcards" element={<PrivateRoute Component={GiftCards} />} />
          <Route path="/my_details" element={<PrivateRoute Component={MyDetails} />} />

          {/* order management routes */}

          <Route path="/select_prescription_type" element={<PrivateRoute Component={SelectLensType} />} />
          <Route path="/select_prescription_Option" element={<PrivateRoute Component={SelectPrescriptionOption} />} />
          <Route path="/select_prescription_Type" element={<PrivateRoute Component={SelectPrescriptionType} />} />
          <Route path="/enter_prescription" element={<PrivateRoute Component={EnterPrescription} />} />

          {/* no page found */}

          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />

        </Routes>

      } />

    </Router>
   ```

   );
   }

   export default App;

Answer (score 0):

While Saunak's answer should suffice, It would be good to separate your content in a protected page and public page and render the navbar conditionally based on user's authenticated state.

```
interface ProtectedElementProps {
  element: React.ReactElement
}

export const ProtectedElement: React.FC<ProtectedElementProps> = ({ element }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

    // If the user is not authenticated, navigate to the login route
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to={routes.login} replace />;
    }

    // If the user is authenticated, render the provided `element` wrapper in your protected navigation
    
    return <Navbar state="private">element</Navbar>;
};
```

```
interface PublicElementProps {
  element: React.ReactElement
  strict?: boolean
}

export const PublicElement: React.FC<PublicElementProps> = ({
    element,
    strict = false // defaults to `false` if not provided
}) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

    // If the user is authenticated and `strict` is `true`, navigate to a different route
    // What strict does is essentially prevents a logged in user from accessing the route
    if (isAuthenticated && strict) {
        return <Navigate to={location.state?.from.pathname ?? routes.dashboard} replace />;
    }

    // Otherwise, render the provided `element` in your public navigation
    return <Navbar state="public">element</Navbar>;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide the Navbar for the signin and signup pages and render it for other pages, you can modify your `App.js` file as follows:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Signin from './Signin';
import Signup from './Signup';
import Home from './Home';
// Import other components...

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        {/* Public Routes */}
        <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />

        {/* Private Routes */}
        <Route
          path="/*"
          element={
            <div>
              <Navbar />
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                {/* Add other private routes here */}
              </Routes>
            </div>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this code, we use the `Router` component from `react-router-dom` to handle routing. We define two types of routes: public routes (signin and signup) and private routes (all other routes). For the public routes, we directly render the corresponding components (`<Signin />` and `<Signup />`).

For the private routes, we wrap them inside a `div` element that contains the `Navbar` component and the nested `Routes` component. This structure ensures that the `Navbar` is rendered only once, and the content inside it (the `Routes` component) changes based on the current route.

You can add additional private routes inside the nested `Routes` component as needed, replacing `<Home />` with the appropriate components for each route.

Make sure to import the necessary components (`Navbar`, `Signin`, `Signup`, etc.) in your `App.js` file or adjust the import statements accordingly.

Note: This example assumes you are using the `react-router-dom` package for routing.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Saunak Ghosh!

Both of your answers so far here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.